# How to get 2 post_type work with each other

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-post-type

How do i get the permalink from cubeportofolio, and the title/thumbnail from posts? With the post_type syntax from wordpress.
here is my code:

```
<?php 

$posts = get_posts(array(
'posts_per_page'   => 1,
'post_type'            => 'cubeportfolio' ));

if( $posts  ): ?>
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

until here the code is oke.
So i am getting the good permalink but my title is wrong, i havent even tried to get the thumbnail.

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'post',
'order'    => 'date'
);              

echo get_the_title($recent)."<br/>";   
wp_reset_postdata();                                
?>                                      


</a>
</li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I have read some things in the documentation but i still cant figure it out.
i want an ul so people can click through the posts but the problem is, i am making my blogs in an plugin. thats the wrong title and thumbnail, So i want the permalink of cubeportfolio(this is an post_type). and I want the title from posts(this is an post_type)

Hole code:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
'post_type'         => 'cubeportfolio',
'order'    => 'date' ));

if( $posts  ): ?>
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'post',
'order'    => 'date'
);              





 echo get_the_title($recent)."<br/>";   


 wp_reset_postdata();                               
 ?>                                     


 </a>
 </li>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>

 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: Do the two types have any connection stored in the database? Or is there any similarity (like content, meta data, category, or something) that can be used to connect the two? How should the function pair a cubeportfolio and a post?

Comment: What do you mean? like is there any data stored in those types? yes both types have an permalink and an title both of them have content, but thats why i dont know how define those types to get them work both. So i can just say: get the title from that post type.

Comment: My question is: you have a custom post type, cubeportfolio, and you have your posts. You want the title of the post with a permalink from cubeportfolio. How do you know which title is paired with which permalink? (So, if you did the pairing manually, how could you do it?)

Comment: so when i make an post it will be the most recent post, i will make the post in cubeportfolio there i will get an permalink and an title. Then i make an post from default wordpress posts there i will upload an title and i will get an permalink. There are the exact same post, because of the wrong permalink from post i will need the permalink of cubeportfolio

Answer (score 0):

Id love to help you out but I would need to understand what it is you are trying to do. From the above code you are pulling in 1 "cubeportfolio" and then doing another query to pull in "posts" and then output their titles. If you are trying to create a unordered list of links to the "cubeportfolio" there is not need for the second query.

```
<?php $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'cubeportfolio',
                  'posts_per_page' => 1,
                  'order' => 'ASC'
             );
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
      <ul>
      <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();
          <li>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a>   
          </li>
      <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

This will only pull in 1 of the "cubeportfolio" items because the query is set to 1 post_per_page. Hope this helps, if not please help me understand your plan and I can update the code to help you out.

Comment: thank you, that you are helping me.
Yes i want an ul so people can click through the posts but the problem is, i am making my blogs in an plugin. thats the wrong title and thumbnail, 
So i want the permalink of cubeportfolio(this is an post_type).
But with your code what i get is the permalink of cubeportfolio and the title from cubeportfolio. Thats not what i want. I want the title from posts(this is an post_type)